# std::pow() output is... special?

Tags: c++, templates, format, pow

Hey all this hopefully is a simple question to answer but it's something entirely new to me and I have no idea why it's happening. Take the following *C++* code:

```
template<class T>
T expo(T a, T b){
    T result = 1;
    while(b) {
        if(b & 1)result *= a;
        b >>=1 ;
        a *= a;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    cout << std::pow<size_t>(50, 5) << endl;
    cout << expo<size_t>(50, 5) << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
3.125e+008
312500000
```

Both are correct but the `std::pow()` formats the output into scientific notation. How in the world does it do this? There must be a feature of *C++* that I've been missing. Help!

Comment: Didn't know `std::pow` is a template. You sure that compiles?

Comment: You're not supposed to explicitly specify template arguments for those functions.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: it's permitted but not required to be a template. So it compiles some places but not everywhere.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - it's not **required** to be a template, and if it is, the effect of explicitly specializing it is not defined by the C++ standard.

Comment: @PeteBecker there's a template version in `<complex>`.

Comment: I ran cout << (double)1565124548216972113 << endl; and noticed that I got the scientific notation I was seeing earlier. I didn't know that it cast to double/float and ignored my template type request

Comment: So what is happening is cout is actually formatting the double given by pow()? That makes much more sense than what I thought was happening

Comment: @Parad0x13 I don't think that's what's happening. Can you try `cout << std::complex<double>(1565124548216972113) << endl;`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - good point. "The effect of instantiating the template complex for any type other than float, double, or long double is unspecified." [complex.numbers]/2.

Comment: cout'ing the complex<> gives output of: (1.56512e+018,0) as expected

Comment: @PeteBecker I doubt it is using a `complex` version on `gcc` and `clang` this code `std::cout << typeid( std::pow<size_t>(50, 5)).name() << std::endl;` returns `d` for `double`.

Comment: @PeteBecker - It's returning a double and not a complex just like you said : 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the basic answer is that:

```
std::pow<size_t>(50, 5)
```

is returning a *double* and therefore the output is defaulting to *scientific* format. If we look at the documentation on *cppreference* [it claims](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) the since *C++11* *integral* arguments are cast to *double* and the output for these cases should be *double*. I am having trouble pinning that strong a statement from the standard but the output is consistent with that explanation.

We can confirm that the output is indeed `double` for at least `gcc` and `clang` using [std::typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

```
std::cout << typeid( std::pow<size_t>(50, 5)).name() << std::endl;
```

which output `d` when we run that through `c++filt -t d` it tells us that it is *double*.

**Update**

Found the relevant section in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf). If we look in section `26` *Numerics library* and then go to section `26.8` *C library* which covers the `<cmath>` header, it specifies overloads of the math functions for *float*, *double* and *long double* which is covered in paragraph *8*:

> In addition to the double versions of the math functions in , C++ adds float and long double overloaded versions of these functions, with the same semantics.

and it covers the *integral* cases in paragraph *11* which says(*emphasis mine*):

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>
> > 1. If any arithmetic argument corresponding to a double parameter has type long double, then all arithmetic arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to long double.
> > 2. Otherwise, if any arithmetic argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double or an integer type, **then all arithmetic arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to double.**
> > 3. Otherwise, all arithmetic arguments corresponding to double parameters have type float.

Comment: Thanks Shafik! I need to learn how to search through the docs better

Comment: @Parad0x13 [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is a great place to start and it usually is accurate although sometimes it is missing examples.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: The reason is easier than it seems, read my answer.

Comment: @MM. nice digging, I looked into it and `__promote_2` looks likes `gcc` implementation of the requirements laid out in `26.8 p 11`, it will invoke `__promote` which will take an *integral* type to *double*.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of `pow` is `double/float` no matter what is the type of input, and the return type of `expo` is `size_t` because compiler instantiates `expo` for `size_t`.
You can use `std::fixed` to make the double format to non-scientific.

**Important update:**

There is a template base declaration for `pow` in gcc (I'm not sure it's standard or not), and it accept types:

```
  template<typename _Tp, typename _Up>
    inline typename __gnu_cxx::__promote_2<_Tp, _Up>::__type
    pow(_Tp __x, _Up __y)
    {
      typedef typename __gnu_cxx::__promote_2<_Tp, _Up>::__type __type;
      return std::pow(__type(__x), __type(__y));
    }
```

The return value is `double/float`.

Comment: I'll need to research a bit more because I don't actually see the double/float conversion. For instance I'm not sure what __promote_2 or __type or __variable are supposed to do. Stuff to learn! lol

Comment: @Parad0x13: You don't have to know about those implementation details. I show that just for say template base `pow` exists in gcc (maybe it's an extension)

Comment: I am pretty sure that `promote_2` from my tests is just doing what `26.8.11` requires. You can see it [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a02061.html#l00173) line 192 and follow back and you can see it will take an *integral* to a *double* as required by the standard.

Comment: @MM. I know, but I would really like to understand everything possible when it comes to Cpp (My favorite language)